# Flutter/Dart app breaking due to change on Firebase Date object

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

My code:

```
void createCloudStoreRecord(FirebaseUser user) {
  // Create/Update user record with uid

  final DocumentReference docRefUsers = Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(user.uid);

  docRefUsers.get().then((datasnapshot) {
    if (datasnapshot.exists) {
      // Exists, so do nothing
    } else {
      // Does not exist, let's create
      Map<String, String> data = <String, String> {
        "email": user.email,
        "photoURL": user.photoUrl,
      };
      // Save data
      docRefUsers.setData(data).whenComplete(() {

      }).catchError((e) => print(e));       
    }
});
```

Error:

```
5.0.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] 
The behavior for system Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK.
To hide this warning and ensure your app does not break, you need to add the following code to your app before calling any other Cloud Firestore methods:
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let settings = db.settings
settings.areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true
db.settings = settings
With this change, timestamps stored in Cloud Firestore will be read back as Firebase Timestamp objects instead of as system Date objects. So you will also need to update code expecting a Date to instead expect a Timestamp. or example:
// old:
let date: Date = documentSnapshot.get("created_at") as! Date
// new:
let timestamp: Timestamp = documentSnapshot.get("created_at") as! Timestamp
let date: Date = timestamp.dateValue()
Please audit all existing usages of Date when you enable the new behavior. In a future release, the behavior will be changed to the new behavior, so if you do not follow these steps, YOUR APP MAY BREAK.
```

Question is: I am just creating a new record; I have not use any Date object at all. Can I safely ignore this warning?

Comment: If you don't use Date you should be safe.

Comment: What's the advised way to get rid of the message from appearing in the logs in flutter?

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to ignore, though [with v0.8.2](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18159#issuecomment-431176341) or the Firebase plugin you can avoid the warning by using the settings:

```
await firestore.settings(timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true);
```